# How to fetch dynamic Tree data using useSWR

Tags: reactjs, tree, swr

I am working on feature to show Tree view using useSWR library in a React application.

Initial data fetches tree up to 4 levels, after that need to use the same API endpoint to get the children tree of a particular leaf node.

Need help to use useSWR approach and append new children data for a particular parent node

Answer (score 0):

For the tree nodes use a separate React component inside where you fetch only the leaf data, again using `useSWR`.

If you've heard about recursion you can also reuse the same component to recursively fetch nested data.

Comment: I thought of this earlier but the UI is not like where can render nested data with in each node or leaf node. I want to use this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-tree` and build some UI like this https://codesandbox.io/s/rd3t-v2-issue-330-repro-forked-q7jhbg